# SQL Server query to get selected rows by adding particular no of days to specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i m having following type of simple sql server table

[image]

Here I want to retrieve all the rows where Notice Created On date + Visibility days are less than or equal to current datetime.

Comment: may be some cast or convert method of SQL date is required as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this, using the [DATEADD function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE GETDATE() <= DATEADD(dd, NoticeVisibilityDays, CreatedOn)
```

Comment: This won't be able to use an index. Use a negative DATEADD on the right side.

Comment: SQL server reports The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Yes, I fixed that. Sorry, try again

Comment: @usr I did not know that, I just flipped and changed the operator instead of needing the negative.

Comment: syntax of dateAdd is DATEADD (datepart , number , date )

Comment: perhaps DateAdd will not work with smalldatetime because sql server reports -  Argument data type smalldatetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Please try my revision. The datetime should go as the 3rd param

Comment: correct syntax that i found is this   DATEADD(DAY , AcademicNotices.NoticeVisibilityDays,AcademicNotices.CreatedOn)

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion i think dd and DAY both works

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Always glad to help, and yah, per the doc d would work also

Comment: in ur answer pls revert the comparison operator from >= to <= because later one works when i checked by filling data :)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Done, however I believe the wording of your question is wrong. I wrote out dates to double check my logic as I always get bit by those operators

Comment: @usr: I don't think that merely shifting the dateadd to the left side of the comparison will lead it to be able to use an index.  I think that in order to be able to do so, you'd need a persisted computed column on dateadd(day, NoticeVisibilityDays, CreatedOn) and index that.

Comment: @BenThul, after the transformation the right side will be constant. SQL Server can use the usual index seek behavior.

Comment: @usr: You're going to have to get specific with your proposal then.  I don't see a way to satisfy the requirements and have the result be sargable.  Both CreatedOn and NoticeVisibilityDays are inputs.  Using either one in dateadd will lead to non-sargability.

Comment: Thats funny. I didn't really look at the query that much - I missed that both inputs on the right side are columns. You are right, then. With the exception, that the column does not need to be persisted. It still can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a visibility of 9 days, your where clause should read

```
   where (created + interval 9 day) <= now()
```

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or now(), etc.

Where are you getting visibility from?

UPDATE:
then use

```
  where (getDate() + interval visibility day) <= now()
```

You can also use

```
  where DATE_ADD(getDate(), interval visibility day) <= now()
```

Comment: default value for createdOn is through (getdate()) , it gives such value 2012-03-26 02:47:00 , visibility i m passing as a parameter